# error:failure reading sector 0x33002 from hd0

Tags: grubrescue

I turned on the laptop and that message has shown on display .... it said

```
failure reading sector 0x33002 from hd0 , entering rescue mode ... grub rescue
```

What should I do ?
I didn't try anything because I didn't find any solution on-line .

Comment: `instmod normal` and then `normal` doesn't work?

Answer (score -1):

Had an error "reading sector 0x5x220 hd0" after installing xubuntu and rebooting.

Typing "instmod normal"  and then "normal"  worked.

Edit:

After another reboot "reading error" occured...